# How to change text color of textviews inside listview row basd on row state (selected, normal, ...)?

Tags: java, android, listview, textview

My row for listview is defined in its own xml file. It contains some textviews.

How can i set the text color of these textviews based on the state of the row (selected , focused, normal ...)?

Answer (score 1):

you have to use setOnFocusChangedListener() for each row . and get access to your textViews, and change the text color.

```
row.setOnFocusChangedListener(focuschangedListener);

private onFocusChangedListener focustchangedListener = new onFocusChangedListener(

            @Override
            public void onFocusChange(View row, boolean arg1) {

                //get access to textviews using row.findViewById()

                if (arg1) {
                     // view is on focus, change the textcolor

                } else {
                     // view lost focus, change the text colors to normal.
                }
            }

);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are setting adapter for listview in your code then override getView of your adapter like this:

```
adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(YourActivity.this , R.layout.liststylelayout)
{

                @Override
                public View getView(int position, View convertView,ViewGroup parent) 
                {
                    View v = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
                    //v is parent view which has your textview as child
                    TextView tv1 =(TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.movielistitemstrings);          
                    //get your textview like this             
                    tv1.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#FF8000"));      
                    //do your operations on textview                
                }                   
};
```